# Ionic Reorder when a google maps marker click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is it possible to reorder ionic list according to the click on a google maps marker?

I have a homepage that has a google map on top with a list under this map. 
I want the list to be reordered when a marker clicked. The item that is related with the marker click will come to the top of the list.

Any idea how to do it or any examples that might help me? Is this feasible with ionic2 and google maps functionalities ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this putting a function call that will sort the list, inside the marker listener. :D So your listener will look like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
        this.map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        this.infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
        this.sortWithMarkerClick(marker_key);
});
```